# How to redirect in Caddyfile keeping some part of the path?

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

I want to redirect URLs like this
`/origin/something` to this `/destination/something`.
I tried to do it using `redir`, but I didn't be able to get just some part of the path by using a placeholder.
Then I tried with rewrite in these ways:

```
rewrite /origin {
  r (.*)
  to /destination{1}
}

rewrite {
  if {path} not_starts_with /origin
  to /{path} /{path}/
}
```

```
rewrite {
  r ^/origin/(.*)
  to /destination{1}
}

rewrite {
  if {path} not_starts_with /origin
  to /{path} /{path}/
}
```

In both ways it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? How can I do this redirection?